# Android / Reading with all of active status bar notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-statusbar, notification-listener

In `NotificationListenerService` class, there are `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` and `onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)` functions, of course.

With `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` function, I can be able to read any new notifications as they come in. Is there any way to read previously posted notifications in the mobile device, that have not yet been dismissed, forever? This has to be done by using my own Android application programmatically.

Comment: `AccessibilityService` class and `NotificationListenerService` class are only can be able to read any new notifications as they come in. Is there any way to read previously posted notifications in the mobile device, that have not yet been dismissed, forever? This has to be done by using my own Android application programmatically.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Within whatever that into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getActiveNotifications()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications()) to get all active notifications which is part of the `NotificationListenerService` class.
The documentation is very clear about this method:

> Request the list of outstanding notifications (that is, those that are visible to the current user). Useful when you don't know what's already been posted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, please let me know if whether this `getActiveNotifications()` function needs to be got overridden within `NotificationListenerService` class or if whether it needs to be got assigned within `StatusBarNotification[]` array inside of some type of thing such as those like overridden `onCreate()` function in `NotificationListenerService` class.

Comment: Please also consider answering my own second question that is available over hereby: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669827/android-overriding-with-onresume-function-of-notificationlistenerservice-cla.

Comment: As per the guidelines of Stack Overflow, a new question itself cannot be posted as a comment or as an answer to an answer but only as a new question itself and by the way that is also true that I feel by posting it but only as a new question itself, furthermore emphasis are can be given with, of course, to that needed highlighted enough type of part of that question, that it is it forever.

Comment: I do appreciate your own promptness of your own answer very much. Done enough.

Comment: @V.Raman You don't need to override it, it's implemented by the service class. You just have to call it once the service is connected (i.e.  `onListenerConnected()` was called).

Comment: I would like to know if whether the `getActiveNotifications()` function should be called on as a plain function without any object bound on to it and without any arguments from the `NotificationListenerService` class that which is inherited from the base class from that which it is used on and if whether inside of what overridden function it should be used on: `onCreate()` function or `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` function or `onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)` function.

Comment: Or if whether it should be called on some object bound on to it with some arguments passed on to it, and if so what object would it be? Or if whether it should be called on without any object bound on to it with some arguments passed on to it?

Comment: By the way, why does the NotificationListenerService class does not have any onResume() function that which can be overridden from the base class from that which it is used on, that which can be called on whenever the activity is resumed for successive times rather than instead of creating the activity for first time? Is there any way to get about that type of thing around it? Please let me know very well about it around that type of thing kindly enough.

Comment: You are missing the fundamentals of the Android main components, like services. A service has no `onResume()` function because it either never stops on its own (called a started service) or stops only if the component bound to it stops (called a bound service). There's no "paused" state since it either runs or it doesn't. For example, a music player usually runs as a foreground service because the user wants it to keep running even if the application (the `Activity`) itself has been closed.

Comment: You may consider posting your last comment as an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669827/android-overriding-with-onresume-function-of-notificationlistenerservice-cla. I will count upvote for it and I will accept your answer as the correct answer which will earn you 25 reputation points. I will also earn 2 reputation points for accepting your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I need at least 75 reputation points (right now I already have 59 reputation points) for placing a bounty on a much needed question of mine that needs to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776167/inflating-a-pop-up-window-parent-viewgroup. Questions with no upvote counts and no answers will automatically get deleted at the end of 1 year (while those with negative number of vote counts and no answers will automatically get deleted at the end of 1 month). It has already been 8 months with that question as of right now, without any answers at all, by right now itself.